# Having one player play multiple characters in Kerberos Club Fate?

Tags: fate, roleplaying, kerberos-club-fate

I'm currently planning a Misfits-style game built in Kerberos-club Fate. Basically a bunch of young offenders with super powers.

One of the players is thinking of a character whose power is that he splits into 2 different characters. They look exactly the same, but have very different personalities. This is directly taken from a character in the show (Rudy, series 3 and onwards), and in the show, it works very well. There's a clear distinction between the characters, and it leads to a lot of great conflict and narrative.

The issue is that I'm not sure it will translate well to Fate. Mechanically it's fine, Kerberos Club actually has a specific "Duplicate" mechanic. I'm just worried about the difficulties in having the player take part in a narrative without confusing people, considering that Fate is very RP-heavy. Is there a way to make it easier without sacrificing story, or might it be a bit much for a Fate game?

Comment: This has @BESW written all over it. There is a specific Fate Fractal for running multiple characters/entities as a single Fate character. See this related question http://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/31381/examples-of-fate-mechanics-for-telling-team-stories-with-one-player

If you ever happen to be on late night/early morning GMT -5 (whatever that translates to for your timezone) you might catch BESW in chat.

Comment: I'm not so sure. Mechanically it's no problem, like I said, KC has rules in place for this kind of thing. The issue is from a roleplaying perspective. Essentially, the player will be talking to herself, and I'm looking for ways to make that less confusing.

Comment: Although our questions are using very different narratives and thus want different mechanics (and so aren't duplicates), we're both worried about the "players talking to themselves" bit. I've not yet found any solutions to implement for my game so I don't have an answer to the question, but I'd love to talk about it in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11/rpg-general-chat) some time; maybe we could figure something out if we put our heads together.

Answer (score 1):

If the system mechanics are not a problem, then this is really a roleplay question, to wit: "Can that specific player successfully portray two identifiable in-game personas at the same time?"

The burden here is mostly on the player rather than the GM. Perhaps it might help to use different accents, or face different directions, like [Gollum's mono-dialogues](http://youtu.be/OkdeyKD5Kt4). In a Fate game (Dresden Files), I and another player each had to distinguish between our base PCs vs the co-dominant spirits in their heads. Separate bodies means your player will also have to manage two sets of physical actions, but it's doable.